# Saving and recalling jQuery selectors

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have an application that saves a clicked on jQuery selector for later use and I am running into a funny issue when I try and recall the selector.  Below is my code for reference.  This is a callback function for an AJAX call that returns a JSON object saved in `data`.  I have verified that the data is getting transfered correctly but it seems like trying to use the string as a selector in jQuery again doesn't work.  The `String()` stuff is just for a test and I am not sure it is necessary.

If anyone has any guidance on why this might not be working I would love to know.  Any code with `jQuery(selector)` just does not function.

```
jQuery.each(data.dot_collection, function() { 
    x_coord = this.x_coord;
    y_coord = this.y_coord;
    selector = new String(this.selector);

    //Works
    alert( selector ); // = html > body.home.blog.logged-in.single-author.two-column.right-sidebar > div.hfeed > header#branding > hgroup > h1#site-title

    //Works
    alert(jQuery("html > body.home.blog.logged-in.single-author.two-column.right-sidebar > div.hfeed > header#branding > hgroup > h1#site-title").offset().left);

    // Not Working & jQuery(selector).offset() = 'undefined'
    alert( jQuery(selector).offset().left );
```

Comment: By the way, `selector = this.selector` doesn't work either.

Comment: Works? http://jsfiddle.net/EVyR2/ Something wrong outside the code you've shown us perhaps?

Comment: I agree there.  I am just not sure what is going on since I can alert the selector and it look just fine.  I can alert out the JSON and it looks fine too.

Comment: This is the JSON I get back for a single point...`{
 "dot_collection":[
  {
   "x_coord":"402",
   "y_coord":"68",
   "created_date":"2011-10-19 12:33:57",
   "number_of_neighbors":0,
   "selector":"html > body.home.blog.logged-in.single-author.two-column.right-sidebar > div.hfeed > header#branding > hgroup > h1#site-title","dot_color":"#7cf27e"
  }
 ]
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the problem is that you are passing a `String` *object* instead of a *primitive string* and jQuery cannot detect this.

Try:

```
var selector = this.selector;
```

Comment: I tried that at first without luck.  The `String()` part was only there as a test so in my code `selector = this.selector` doesn't work either.

Comment: @Ryan: What does `jQuery(selector).length` give you?

Comment: It gives me zero (0).  It is just an empty object.

Comment: @Ryan: I think you have to create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo... obviously something is wrong but I can tell you that passing a variable holding a selector works in general.

Comment: I will set up a live site if that helps that shows the error.  I haven't used jsfiddle but I am guessing that it doesn't function terribly well if my data is stored on a local db.

Comment: http://selector.swampedpublishing.com/  In the bottom right you will see a 'Display Heatmap'.  If you click on that the AJAX should run.  You may have to add a point by clicking somewhere on the page (not a link).

Comment: the first selector i get is `html > body.home blog single-author two-column right-sidebar`. doesn't look quite right.

Comment: @Tetaxa No, that doesn't look right at all.  Hmm, I will take a look.

Comment: @Tetaxa: How did you get that result?  I can't seem to recreate it.

Comment: @Ryan I dunno, clicked it. I don't get that now. However, your inline string selector doesn't work for me but the variable `selector` does...

Comment: @Tetaxa: Are you saying that `alert(selector)` works but jQuery(selector) will not select correctly for you?   That is what I am finding also.

Comment: No, `alert( selector )` works, `alert(jQuery("html > ... h1#site-title").offset().left)` does not work, `alert( jQuery(selector).offset().left )` works.

Comment: Hmmm, OK.  Well thanks, I am not sure how `alert( jQuery(selector).offset().left )` starting working.  But count it as another win for stack overflow.  I hope I didn't waste anyone's time.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('p').each(function() { 
    console.log(this.offsetLeft);
});
```

By using this, I can get offset left for each p (collection in your case).